# Read Office 365 email (Exchange Online) calendar in SharePoint Online site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, csom, jsom

Need to read a specific person's(eg: MD) calendar from his Exchange Online account and show the calendar appointments in a SharePoint Online page. It is possible to read other user's Exchange Online Calendar events through JSOM or CSOM in SharePoint 2013 (O365).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried browsing the [Office 365 API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog)?

Comment: Yes. I seen the same pages. Noticed that, we need to create an access token and outlook client service object. But failed to use access token and outlook client object with Rest API urls in a sample. Any other suggestions to use API with user's credentials will helpful.